# Is there a defined list of possible Vimeo resolutions?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player, vimeo-android, pyvimeo

I noticed if you upload a video to Vimeo via the api, and the resolution is something non-standard, it will normalize the height during transcoding. Ie, I had a video that was 1920x1050 (NOT 1080), and vimeo normalized it to 1906x1080.

Is there a finite list of heights that Vimeo normalizes to? Or is it a function that can produce any number of different heights?

This might seem simple for 16:9 videos, but what about vertical phone videos? What height do those normalize to?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a link to the video on Vimeo? Odd that the width (1920) was scaled down (to 1906) while the height (1050) was scaled up (to 1080)

Comment: I think they decided to standardize the heights rather than the width, that's why

Answer (score 0):

The logic behind the video dimensions generated by Vimeo's transcoders is documented here: https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/224820827-Determining-playback-resolution

Comment: Thank you; I should have mentioned I did see this. I uploaded a phone video like I mentioend though, and the resulting resolution was 352x640. That case doesn't seem to be documented here